# Get a portion of numbers from a pandas column with dtype int

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I get the first 8 digits from a column with 15 digits?

```
data = [['tom', 355552107972100], ['nick', 356557107972103], ['juli', 455552107972100]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Code'])
```

```
    Name    Code
0   tom     355552107972100
1   nick    356557107972103
2   juli    455552107972100
```

I want to create a new column with the first 8 digits from the code column

Answer (score 3):

Convert values to strings and use indexing:

```
df['Code'] =  df['Code'].astype(str).str[:8].astype(int)
```

Or:

```
df['Code'] =  df['Code'].map(lambda x: int(str(x)[:8]))
```

Or use integer division (working correct if always 15 digits):

```
df['Code'] = df['Code'] // 10000000
```

Answer (score 1):

[@jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71065843/5353753) comment is correct, but you can also divide each number by `10000000`, and convert to int:

```
df['Code'] = (df['Code']/10000000).astype('int')
```

This will result in trimming the 7 right digits.